# bind key to complete filename wherever the context is in Zsh

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

Sometimes I want a filename instead of what zsh guesses for me. For example, I have a PNG file without a proper `.png` suffix, which makes zsh think it isn't a picture and won't list it when I type `Tab` to complete arguments of `display`.

I am wondering if there is a key sequence that completes for a filename wherever the context is, like `^XC` for `_correct_filename`, or how to configure zsh to do the thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a key binding to do what you want:

```
zle -C complete complete-word complete-files
bindkey '^X\t' complete
complete-files () { compadd - $PREFIX* }
```

**Edit:** Added `$PREFIX`

You can add those lines to your `~/.zshrc` file.

That makes the completion list all files when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> at each step instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>. You could choose another keystroke combination that suits you.

Or to make ImageMagick completions always include all files, try editing (make a backup first) the file `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_imagemagick` (or similar) and change this to comment out the existing line that begins with `_files` and add the new one shown:

```
if (( $# )); then
  # _files "$@" -g "*.(#i)(${~formats//:/|})(-.)"
  _files "$@"
  return
fi
```

Comment: Useful but not very ideal. The `complete-files` function can only complete files under current directory. I've tried `_files` instead of it but got a `(eval):1: no matches found: *:all-files` error. Is there a way to make it behave like when completing after `cat`?
I want it to complete not only for `display`, so the latter doesn't suit my situation.

Comment: @lilydjwg: I don't understand. For me, complete-files functions with completing for display the same way that regular completion works for cat (except the file-type suffixes such as "@" and "*" aren't added. When I do regular tab-completion for cat I only get files in the current directory.

Comment: I mean, if I type a path (eg ./ or ../ or abc/, with '/' in what I've typed) and then trigger the function, nothing will be shown.

Comment: @lilydjwg: I added the `$PREFIX` variable in the `complete` function. See if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Dennis' answer didn't expand tilde for me, so I would get stuff like `complete-files: no matches found: ~/ma*` when I tried to invoke it on `foo ~/ma`. I did find an alternate in the [zsh FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq04.html#l52) that will expand them, though:

```
zle -C complete-file complete-word _generic
zstyle ':completion:complete-file::::' completer _files
bindkey '^xF' complete-file
```