# How to force filename completion under oh-my-zsh?

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

**The problem:**

Sometimes, when I try to do things in zsh, it won't complete the filenames I want because they don't apply to the current context. Two examples:

1. I want to force-add a file which is currently ignored in hg or git. oh-my-zsh tries to help me by only completing non-ignored files, but in this case it is a hindrance. I'm forced to type the full path to the file manually.
2. I want to use `git diff` to diff two arbitrary files on my hard drive. These files do not reside in any repository, but who cares?! `git diff --no-index` is a really nice way to diff any two files. But because they aren't in a repo, zsh won't complete them.

**The proposed solution:**

I *could* simply edit the source control context to complete all filenames, regardless of their source control status. But there are a couple limitations:

1. I don't know how to do that.
2. It might be nice to have an "escape hatch" whereby I could *force* file completion, no matter what the context.

So, I decided instead to bind a key shortcut to force normal, context-free file completion.

**What I have so far:**

Zsh apparently has an easy way of doing this, as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658534/bind-key-to-complete-filename-wherever-the-context-is-in-zsh). So I've added the following lines to my `.zshrc`:

```
zle -C complete complete-word complete-files
bindkey '^[[Z' complete
complete-files () { compadd - $PREFIX* }
```

This causes *shift-tab* to initiate file completion. It works beautifully in standard zsh! But boo-hoo, for some reason it doesn't work when I source oh-my-zsh. :-(

**So is there a way to get this to work with oh-my-zsh, or is there an alternative solution I might find satisfying?**

Comment: At some point oh-my-zsh may remove previous bindings. You can check if the binding is still present in the running shell with `bindkey | grep '^[[Z'`. You also can check if the zle setting is correct with `zle -lL complete` and the function definition with `whence -c complete-files`.

Comment: You're completely right! As long as I call `bindkey` _after_ sourcing `oh-my-zsh.sh`, it's all good. (oh-my-zsh binds it to `reverse-menu-complete`) If you want to add an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

My way of doing exactly that (replacing the default `diff` command with the one from `git`) was pretty straightforward.

Add this to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
diff() {
    git diff --no-index "$@"
}
```

Before I was using an alias, but since zsh can "solve" them, it was then using the autocompletion functions from `git diff`, which inadvertently led to the same problem as you.

Using a function solves this issue as zsh reverts to the classic "files only" completion.